# Searching for sci-fi film where several characters are alone on an alien planet and there's a large alien "cube" and some organism attacking them

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

Sadly, I don't remember a great deal about this movie other than a specific scene where there are three to five(?) characters in some kind of shuttle or base on an alien planet. Can't remember why they're there (don't think they crashed, but don't think they can leave either). At some point in the scene a couple of the characters come across a very large (technological looking?) cube. During this section of the film one or more of the characters are attacked or infected by something alien and it starts to morph/affect the character(s). I think there was foliage on the planet/in the scene.

Not clear on when it was out either - could be anywhere from 90's to 2010 (I doubt it's later than 2010). I'd most likely go for between '98 and '08.

Have tried sifting through countless review sites, sci-fi film lists and even AI searches, to no avail. Am beginning to wonder if I dreamt it!

Sorry, I don't remember much more than that. Deepest of thanks for any help you can give.

Definitely a film, not a TV show/series.
Characters were in space suits / were astronauts
Was set in future (i.e. not modern astronauts)
The cube looked (could be misremembering here) like it was technological in nature, so had a wiring kind of design rather than something smooth, or stone-like.
I imagine it was not a blockbuster, but also not a terrible hatchet job of a copy (i.e. a mockbuster).

Films that it's not:
Stranded (Christian Slater)
Project Gemini (Serik Beyseu)

Comment: The premise of a cube on a planet reminds me of the movie _[2036 Origin Unknown (2018)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2036_Origin_Unknown)_. Other than that, it's not a match.

Comment: In roughly which year did you actually watch this?

Comment: All I can imagine are Borg cubes.

Comment: Did the cube do anything (at least visibly)?  Did it chase the characters, extrude appendages to attack with, zap them somehow...?

Comment: Reminds me somewhat [Galaxy Of Terror (1981)](https://youtu.be/uwMbdUBSmo4?t=1473)